# zsh cd tab completion matching

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying out zsh and there's a tab-completion behavior that I'm finding annoying: It seems that if I type `cd str` and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>, it will auto complete with `*str*`. For example, `cd pl` <kbd>TAB</kbd> results in an autocompletion of `cd Applications/` because 'Ap**pl**ications' contains 'pl'.

Is there a way to turn this off?

I know zsh has a tab completion feature where `cd /u/loc/b` <kbd>TAB</kbd> will get you to `/usr/local/bin`. Is this behavior related?

- Operating System: OSX 10.11
- Zsh version: 5.0.8
- oh-my-zsh plugins: git, zsh-syntax-highlighting, z

**UPDATE**

I've tracked the offending block of code down to my `~/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh` file.

```
67 if [[ $ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX != true ]]; then
68   # If completion insecurities exist, warn the user without enabling completions.
69   if ! compaudit &>/dev/null; then
70     # This function resides in the "lib/compfix.zsh" script sourced above.
71     handle_completion_insecurities
72   # Else, enable and cache completions to the desired file.
73   else
74     compinit -d "${ZSH_COMPDUMP}"
75   fi
76 else
77     compinit -i -d "${ZSH_COMPDUMP}"
78 fi
```

I'm still reading documentation and trying to figure out exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. I think I've got it sorted out. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226685/have-zsh-return-case-insensitive-auto-complete-matches-but-prefer-exact-matches) was very helpful.

Basically, oh-my-zsh sets the completion to

`zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'`

Removing `'l:|=* r:|=*'` (which is the last rule) now gives me the desired behavior.

The ability to do `cd /u/lo/b/` <kbd>TAB</kbd> is not compromised.